# Why is it possible to use these abstract methods?

Tags: java, android, oop

Consider this code from this page 
[Saving key - value sets](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

Why is it possibile to just use the putInt() method without providing an implementation since it's an abstract method? (see: [SharedPreferences.Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29))
Shouldn't that be impossible to do?
Would you kindly explain this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is it possibile to just use the putInt() method without providing an implementation since it's an abstract method?

`editor` is an instance of an internal class that implements the `SharedPreferences.Editor` interface. Most likely, it is an instance of [`SharedPreferencesImpl.EditorImpl`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java).

Comment: Though both answer are valid I guess this is a bit more complete and leads me to understand better how that worked

Answer (score 5):

As long as you have an instance of an object, there is no such thing as an abstract method. All instances are concrete and completely defined. Here you get an instance returned by `sharedPref.edit()`, therefore you are able to call `putInt` on it.